# How to eliminate duplicate legends in Plotly with subplot (Python)?

Tags: python, plotly

The following codes generate 2 plotly charts and lay them out in subplots. Each subplot contains legends that partially overlap with another subplot. As a result, there are duplicated legends on the right. Does anyone know a better way to eliminate duplicated legends in this situation? Thanks.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

f1 = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], name="A"),
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1], name="B")
])
f2 = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 5, 4, 5], name="B"),
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[5, 4, 1, 2, 1], name="C")
])

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['F1', 'F2'])

for ea in f1.data:
    fig.add_trace(ea, row=1, col=1)
    
for ea in f2.data:
    fig.add_trace(ea, row=1, col=2)
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be several ways to do this, but the easiest is to set the second graph to specify the color and hide the legend.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['F1', 'F2'])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], name="A", legendgroup='A'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1], name="B", legendgroup='B'), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[1, 2, 5, 4, 5],
        line=go.scatter.Line(color='#EF553B'),
        name="B",
        legendgroup='B',
        showlegend=False
    ), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[5, 4, 1, 2, 1],
        line=go.scatter.Line(color='#00cc96'),
        name="C",
        legendgroup='C',
        showlegend=True
    ), row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

[image]

legend 'B' toggle

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I just revised my question. Each subplot contains legends that partially overlap with another subplot. Hiding one of the legends won't help.

Comment: The question has been updated and I have modified the code. If my understanding is different, please comment.

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. Your method works. But when there are 10-20 subplots with hundreds of overlapping legends, would you still recommend this method?

Comment: For example, depending on the shape of the data, if it is a data frame, add a column of legend names and use a loop process in the graphing code to determine the data. Another way is to create a list of True, False in advance and loop through the list. In the example in your question, the list would be `flg=[True,True,False,True]`. You set that with `showlegend=flg`.

Comment: That will work. I wish that Plotly could handle this kind of thing automatically like Matplotlib.

Comment: There is a problem with this technique. When you toggle legend "B" (red), only the red line on the left subplot is responding. The red line on the right subplot is not responding.

Comment: That's right, plotly allows you to set up legend groups, so I set up legend B as a group.

Comment: Great! You nail it again. Thanks!